# Android crash report button not shown

Tags: android, crash, report

I have developed an app and want to make sure that whenever an unexpected crash occurs, the user is able to send a crash report.

From Android 2.2 onward I read that Android has something build in for this. However, in my case, the application crashes in one special situation, but only the "Force close" button is shown.

The button is not shown in the app downloaded from the Market as well as when I install it directly on my telephone.

Must I perform some programmatic effort to achieve this?

Comment: No coding will help.I think you have to enable some feature in your android market developer account.so that users can submit the crash reports.

Comment: Any luck on this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get crash dialog with report button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552963/how-to-get-crash-dialog-with-report-button)

Answer (score 0):

Crash report options are given to users of Android >= 2.2. As a developer you don't need to do anything with your code just monitor your developer account for crash/freeze reports.

See [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/google-feedback-for-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Crash Report SDK](https://github.com/liu-yanjun/crash-log-report) in your project. If an unexpected crash occurs, it will be reported to the [crashlog.org](http://www.crashlog.org) platform. You can view the crash log on this platform, where offers Stack traces, Memory, Storage, Thread and Process information for debugging.