# How to get crash dialog with report button

Tags: android

I purposely make my own application crash. I get the following dialog.

[image]

However, I wish to get the following crash dialog with report button.

[image]

May I know how I can do so? I had signed my application. (But I transfer the APK locally to my phone, not through Android market). I still can't get the `Report` button.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I know, the `Report` button only shows when the app is installed via the Market (i.e. is signed and not in debug mode nor with a debug key). This data is all shown in LogCat if you are USB debugging.

**Edit**: Also, you can catch this information and file a report yourself if you want, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application) method.

Comment: I had signed it. But I do not install it through Android market. Does it matter?

Comment: You installed it via USB? Yes, it matters. The `Report` data is sent to the Developer Console on the Google Play system, therefore the Report button will only show up if it is downloaded via Google Play (Android Market, whatever :P).

Comment: @Eric so even if you compile a signed APK and install it via adb the report option won't show?

Comment: @JMRboosties Correct.

Comment: This is such an annoyance. Any reason why play store can't just verify that the app has a known certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) library in your app. This basically "is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their crash reports to a GoogleDoc form". You can modify its use to pop up a dialog like the above, and ask the user to report the issue, with an additional user-typed message, even.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone may running a customized rom like CM.
If you want to report log when your app get FC,one way is catch exceptions and mail them.