# No report option when getting "Unfortunately 'app name' has stopped"

Tags: android, google-play, crash-reports

My app is on Google Play store. One of the users reported that the app sometimes crashes when trying to open it. He sent a screenshot in which a dialog says the app has stopped, with just an OK button and no option to report about the crash.
Any idea why there is no option to report? How can I get a report so I can try to solve the issue?

Comment: The standard crash dialog doesn't have a report button.  If you want one, you can try a 3rd party library like ACRA.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan, I did get crash reports from users before, so how does it make sense?

Comment: That user must not have installed from the Google Play Store. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552963/how-to-get-crash-dialog-with-report-button